# IE8 strange issue background not loading

Tags: php, css, joomla

I recently made a website which has a very strange issue blowing my mind.

If some one can test the blow two urls and tell me how can i debug this issue ?

I have two hosting servers

Website hosted on server1:

http://test.ici.com.pk/

Website hosted on server2:

http://ici.com.pk/

I have copied same website + database on both servers (uploaded 3 times to verify)

Strange issue is that IE8 not loading blue background in SERVER2

Unable to debug is this is the issue from server side setting or css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that these two websites have totally different sources, you would've see yourself if you took a look at page source on browser.

And I guess the problem with IE is IE's ridiculous 32 stylesheets limit. 
http://drupal.org/node/228818

First you should find out why page source if different (wrong template?) then you may need to merge some of your stylesheets and keep their count below 32 for IE (e.g http://drupal.org/node/510442).

Comment: Thanks for saving my life..! it was the issue with large number of CSS i enabled the CSS MINIFY option with Joomla and Everything goes perfect

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with the virtual host....try to configure the virtual host for SERVER2 proper that doesnt leads conflicts to you

Comment: SERVER2 is unmanaged, can you give a hint for proper virtual host ?

Comment: In your pc you will access your files like /var/www/myproj_folder or like 192.192.33.111/myproj_folder with your IP right..??instead this create a virtual host that will helps you to redirect to your project main on basics of your virtual host that you are created